# Having an Error with React, Jest and Enzyme setup

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme

I am trying to setup my test environment in my React project and facing an issue while setting up jest and enzyme. Adding my code files for reference.

Following is my code:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.config.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "save": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "jest": "^23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.2",
    "enzyme": "3.4.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.2.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4"
  }
```

**jest.config.js**

```
import { shallow, render, mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "env", "stage-1"]
}
```

When I run, npm run test, I face the following issue:

```
import { shallow, render, mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Please let me know if someone's faced something similar and found a solution.

Comment: try to change the `jest.config.js` to `setupTests.js`, probably jest thinks that `jest.config.js` is the default jest config as outlined in here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#docsNav

Comment: that worked, thanks !

Comment: great, then I will post it as an official answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest is looking for `jest.config.js` to check the config by default as outlined [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#docsNav).

So it tries to parse your code as a config, and jest itself runs in a vanilla node environment thus it doesn't understand `import, export` syntax (yet).

So the easiest fix is to name your `jest.config.js` something like `setupTests.js`.

Hope it helps.

### Update: (more in-depth answer, as requested in comments)

#### So let's trace the error:

Initially, `jest` [tries](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/698c33c26272742b05d88c2b9169a13acc4121a1/packages/jest-config/src/index.js#L85) based on whether you have used `--config` argument to detect your main config path before everything else.

For that, since you didn't provide the `--config` option, it defaults to checking first if you have a default `jest.config.js` or otherwise `package.json` where it tries to get the `jest` property.

But since you have a `jest.config.js` file it is detected [first](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/698c33c26272742b05d88c2b9169a13acc4121a1/packages/jest-config/src/resolveConfigPath.js#L59), and
[read](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/698c33c26272742b05d88c2b9169a13acc4121a1/packages/jest-config/src/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js#L26) where it happily explodes, and since it's not a `JSON` files, you don't get a pretty error, instead you get the error rethrown further into stdout as it is. And that's what you see on the screen.

Which means, at this stage, the config is detected to be `jest.config.js`, so the `package.json` config is being completely ignored whatsoever, even if it didn't explode it would still miss the whole config in the `package.json`.

So as you see, it's wrong on many levels, and the only way to fix it and let the standard flow work is not to use `jest.config.js` and instead use any other file name.

Comment: Karen.. your answer works great. However, in the link mentioned by you, I could not find any explanation that why setupTests.js works but not jest.config.js. Would really appreciate if you can explain that a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

npm install enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16 enzyme-to-json --save-dev

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Comment: So you cannot explain this? Or decline explaining this? Anyway, I routinely doubt everything which has no explanation. I sometimes use things which work, in spite of not understanding them, I consider that useful maigc. But a good StackOverflow answer I expect to have an explanation, because it enables to learn and build upon.

Comment: we have a different development environment, so the error could be different from one another. my answer is simple commend if u run this comment it will install these as dev dependencies, there is nothing to explain.  if u search for this library u can easily understand.